# VideoView crop to square

Tags: android, video, crop, android-videoview

Using an `ImageView`, I can set a square height and width (say 100dip x 100dip). Then using `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` gives me an image which is cropped to square regardless of aspect ratio.

Can we do this with a `VideoView`?

I've tried just setting a square height and width, but it just re-sizes to fill the square as best as it can while maintaining the aspect ratio, which I guess is completely expected.

It doesn't seem to have any scale or crop properties / methods unlike `ImageView`, but this in the `VideoView` documentation makes me think I'm missing something:

> [VideoView] ...provides various display options
>   such as scaling and tinting.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Source](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/VideoView.java) implies that it isn't natively supported in the VideoView view. You could copy the source and make it work though. :) Most likely by adding an **else** at line 255, modifying onMeasure to prevent it from expanding to meet the size, etc.

Edit:
Don't be surprised that the Reference documentation is slightly off or just plain wrong.

Comment: Sweet, thanks, just a shame I ended this project a while ago now! :)

Comment: @Andy did you try to achieve the square video?

Comment: @Naz141 not sure I did. Think I might have cropped the source video since it was for demo purposes.

Answer (score 4):

You achive video crop effect using [`TextureView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) which require Android API 14 and hardware acceleration. I described it in my article [here](https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/dmytrodanylyk/blob/gh-pages/articles/surface-view-video-cropping.md).

You can also use my [`TextureVideoView`](https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/android-video-crop) - custom view based on android `TextureView` which gives you ability to easy play and crop video. This very similar to `ImageView#setScaleType`

Layout

```
<com.dd.crop.TextureVideoView
        android:id="@+id/cropTextureView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>
```

Code

```
TextureVideoView cropTextureView = (TextureVideoView) findViewById(R.id.cropTextureView);
// Use `setScaleType` method to crop video
cropTextureView.setScaleType(TextureVideoView.ScaleType.TOP);
// Use `setDataSource` method to set data source, this could be url, assets folder or path
cropTextureView.setDataSource("http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4");
cropTextureView.play();
```

Hope this will help someone!